# Laravel SQL issue SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

when I use php artisan migrate, I get this error

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations)

 at        /Users/jasonb/code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
663|         catch (Exception $e) {
664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
  /Users/jasonb/code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=test", "root", "jasonb", [])
  /Users/jasonb/code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I read few posts but I still can't fix... what can be wrong? 
my .env file is correct...

Comment: try `mysql -uroot -pjasonb` from console

Comment: The error is saying that the MySQL user `root` is using an incorrect password. You should check that A) you are connecting to the correct DB, and B) the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache
```